# Minimum value selection

Tags: functions

Code

```
 y[1] = 1;
 y[2] = 2;
 y[3] = 3;
 Min[y[1], y[2], y[3]]
```

Outputs "1", but desired result is `y[1]`

How to do that? Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the value(s) i for which `y[i]` is minimal :

```
 y[1] = 10;
 y[2] = 20;
 y[3] = 30;
 MinimalBy[Range[3],y]
```

> {1}

But as soon as you wrap the result 1 in `y[...]`, `y[1]` will be evaluated to 10, accordingly to the princips of Mathematica.

Comment: `HoldForm[y[n]] /. n -> First@MinimalBy[Range[3], y]` gives `y[1]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Your answer help me a lot. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For the exact example given you could perhaps utilize the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) list:

```
MinimalBy[DownValues[y], Last][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> HoldPattern[y[1]]
> ```