# function restorage problem

Tags: functions, variable

Code below

```
f[1, 1] = 1;
f[1, 2] = 2;
f[1] = Min[f[1, 1], f[1, 2]]
```

Outputs

```
1
```

However, the desired output is

```
f[1,1]
```

That means restorage of the assigning function.

What should I do? Many thanks.

Comment: I think there is a deeper problem here, considering all the other questions you've asked. What exactly are you trying to do here? (Also, since `f[1, 1]` and `f[1, 2]` automatically evaluate to their corresponding values, what you are then actually doing is `f[1] = Min[1, 2]`.)

Comment: As @J.M. notes you're thinking about this problem wrong. You want to choose the set of arguments that minimizes your function, `f`. So you'll want to reformulate the way you write this, probably using [`MinimalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html.en)

Comment: This appears to be the same question you asked in [(152537)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152537/27951), which received some interesting suggestions as well. In this form, I would vote to close as a duplicate, but as @J.M. and @b3m2a1 pointed out, there is probably a fundamental misunderstanding that needs to be resolved. Could you tell us *why* you need such a result? In addition to the methods proposed, you could perhaps use an `Association` construct to store the function form and its values separately, but to help you further we need to know what you want to do ultimately!

Comment: @J.M.What I am trying to do is that getting feedback of assigning function, not the value which the corresponding function is equal to

Comment: "getting feedback of assigning function" - yes, but why? What application is this that you need to do these things?

Comment: @MarcoB My work is much too complicated to present here, so a simple case is raised, of which the solution contains the code I need

Comment: Unless you become more willing to give explanatory details to differentiate/elaborate this problem, I'm marking it as a dupe: `MinimalBy[Range[2], f[1, #] &]`

Comment: @Robin_Lyn I understand that this is a simplified example, but perhaps you may have oversimplified it to the point that we cannot see the utility of the behavior your request. Try and tell us what you want to do with the output in the step following the one you described. Perhaps that's might help understand your application.

Comment: @J.M.Optimizaition theory, Hooke-Jeeves method. After comparing values of three vectors, a new vector generates. Values are function values, and vectors are independent variables contained by assigning function. And further circle calculation needs the new vector.

Comment: I am quite familiar with [Hooke-Jeeves](https://doi.org/10.1145/321062.321069), and now my suspicion is even stronger that you are going about things wrong. Just have the relevant vectors be represented as lists in *Mathematica*. You can use `Pick[]` for selections like `veclist = IdentityMatrix[3]; vallist = {3, -2, 0}; Pick[veclist, vallist, Min[vallist]][[1]]`.